# Quaggga OSPFv3 won't configure routes

Tags: networking, router, routing, ipv6, openwrt

I'm trying to configure Quagga to use OSPFv3 to create proper IPv6 routes between two OpenWrt routers running OpenVPN (tun mode). I know the tunnel is working properly because it works if I configure the routes manually.

Both routers have a link-local address on the tun0 interface, and I can actually see OSPFv3 packets between the routers, but the routes are not being set-up in the routing table. I would also like to point out that OSPFv2 does work so this is probably not a permission issue.

I'm attaching the ospf6d.conf files from both routers, I'd appreciate any insights regarding possible misconfiguration.

OpenVPN server side:

```
hostname gateway
password *********
enable password *********
log file /tmp/zebra-ospf6d.log

!
!
!
interface default
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface br-lan
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface eth0
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface eth0.1
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface lo
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface pppoe-wan
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface tun0
  no ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface wlan0
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface tun1
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface tun2
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!

router ospf6
  router-id 192.168.92.2
  redistribute kernel
  interface br-lan area 0.0.0.0
  interface tun0 area 0.0.0.0
  interface tun1 area 0.0.0.0
  interface tun2 area 0.0.0.0
  area 0.0.0.0 range 2000::/3
  area 0.0.0.0 range fc00::/7
!
line vty
!
end
```

OpenVPN client side:

```
hostname gateway
password *********
enable password *********
log file /tmp/zebra-ospf6d.log


!
!
!
interface default
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface br-lan
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface eth0
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface eth0.1
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface lo
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface pppoe-wan
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface tun0
  no ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface tun1
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface wlan0
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!
interface wlan1
  ipv6 ospf6 passive
!

router ospf6
  router-id 192.168.92.1
  redistribute kernel
  interface br-lan area 0.0.0.0
  interface tun0 area 0.0.0.0
  interface tun1 area 0.0.0.0
  area 0.0.0.0 range 2000::/3
  area 0.0.0.0 range fc00::/7
!
line vty
!
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do the routers exchange DB packets (not just HELLO)? I don't exactly remember the v6 commands, but are the routes visible internally to Quagga itself in `show ipv6 route`? Does `show ipv6 ospf neighbor` show the adjacency stuck at init, or something like that? Are the routers able to ping each other using their *link-local* v6 addresses?

Comment: (Does OpenWRT not have FRR yet? Quagga hasn't been maintained for a few years now; FRR is the replacement, Bird2 is a good alternative.)

Comment: I can see DB Description, LS Request, LS Update and LS Acknowledge packets. Would you like me to upload a tcpdump capture?

Comment: Also, yes, I know I'm not using the latest OpenWrt version as it would be very painful to upgrade right now (one of the routers doesn't even have enough flash for the latest build). I'm just keeping track of security issues.

Comment: The routes don't show up even internally